# How to disable a buttons in a custom cell?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a custom cell built it with the storyboard that has the following components:

1 UIImage
2 UILabels
4 UIbuttons

One button allows users save coupons as favorite, I would like to set this button disable after the user save the coupon, I have tried to add an IBOutlet for the button in the custom cell class but it doesn’t work and I don’t get any error. How can I do this? Somebody can help me?

**The Code:**

**CouponsCell.h**

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIButton *saveFav;
```

**CouponsCell.m**

```
#import "CouponsCell.h"

@implementation CouponsCell
@synthesize saveFav;

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}
@end
```

I have made the connection between the IBOutlet and the button and when the user touch the button I tried this:

```
- (IBAction)AddFavorite:(id)sender {

    CGPoint buttonPosition = [sender convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:self.tableView];
    NSIndexPath * indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:buttonPosition];
    Coupons * couponsObjects = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    CouponsCell *couponsCell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CouponCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    idCoupon = cuponesObjects.idCoupons;

    Reachability *reachability = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];
    [reachability startNotifier];
    NetworkStatus status = [reachability currentReachabilityStatus];

    if ( status == NotReachable )
    {
        UIAlertView *message = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"CC Galerias"
                                                          message:@"Can’t save the Coupon to favorite, Check your Internet connection."
                                                         delegate:nil
                                                cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                otherButtonTitles:nil];

        [message performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(show) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
    }
    else if ( status == ReachableViaWiFi )
    {
        [self postCouponFav:idCoupon]; // Save the Coupon to Favorites
        [couponsCell.saveFav setEnabled:NO]; // Set diseable the button


    }
    else if ( status == ReachableViaWWAN )
    {
        [self postCouponFav:idCoupon];
        [couponsCell.saveFav setEnabled:NO];

    }

}
```

Please help me, maybe the solutions is easy but I learning iOS development. Thanks in advance for help me.

Comment: Please change your subject to use mixed case (no yelling) and change it to a proper title that reflects your question.

Comment: If you place a breakpoint in AddFavorite method the execution is it stopped ?

Comment: Sorry I am new in stackoverflow, I already change the title...

Comment: @tdelepine Yes, it is... The coupon is saved as favorite, but doesn't change the state to disable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use dequeue because the return cell is a new instance of the cell and not the cell displayed.

Your are two way for change the button state.

- Transport your (IBACTION)method in your custom cell class and not in controller class and release legacy code. If you need to update data between CustomCell and controller create and invoke a delegate.
- The second way is to reload the Cell of UITableView after setting necessary values for presented the well state